# Mac OS VPN uses default Subnet Mask

Tags: networking, macos, vpn

We expanded our subnet mask from 255.255.255.0 to 255.255.254.0 to incorporate more IP addresses in the business: 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.1.255 is the new subnet.

All of the servers etc are on the 192.168.1.x range, and when the Macs connect via VPN they might pick up an IP from the 192.168.0.x range. This wouldn't be an issue if they also picked up the correct subnet mask or allowed us to manually change this. Unfortunately they pick up a default class C subnet and we're unable to change it.

We've tried setting manual IP addresses on Macs for VPN but this doesn't seem to work and would require us to set manual IPs and reserve them on DHCP which would be a pain.

Is there a way to get the Macs to pick up the new subnet mask or manually set it to 255.255.254.0? Or even restrict the RRAS server to only giving out addresses from the 192.168.1.x range?

Comment: Doesn't the RRAS server have this configurable as well? (Might be under 'routes'.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restricted the address pool on the server to a list of static IP addresses in the 192.168.1.x IP range.

Did this by right-clicking the server in Routing and Remote Access --> Properties --> IPv4 --> Static Address Pool.

Still a bit strange that Mac OS doesn't allow you to set a subnet mask manually or pick up the correct one, but this solution works for us at the moment.